# how can I get all comments from a url in facebook?

Tags: comments, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get all the comments of a url that was added to facebook. is this possible?

Comment: It's not really clear what you means by saying "URL added to Facebook".

Answer (score 13):

It is possible to get all comments (from [Comments social plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)) associated with URL by issuing next request to Graph API:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=URL
```

For example some article on TechCrunch:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=http%3A%2F%2Ftechcrunch.com%2F2012%2F02%2F27%2Fyahoo-stabs-facebook-in-the-back-says-pay-for-its-patents-or-get-sued%2F
```

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work anymore. Response ssays: `(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (comments) on node type (URL)`

Comment: You can see answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62490401/304894