# get list of all comments using url?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I viewed this question before asking ,but it dint help.

[Facebook Graph API get all comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439804/facebook-graph-api-get-all-comments)

[how can I get all comments from a url in facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487831/how-can-i-get-all-comments-from-a-url-in-facebook)

I am trying to fetch all comments from two url.

1. www.arrowlife.com?section=Destined-for-stardom
2. www.arrowlife.com?section=section=The-Improviser

What I have done:

I url encoded the above urls and passed in the url like this:https://graph.facebook.com/www.arrowlife.com%3Fsection%3DDestined-for-stardom/comments

Where am i going wrong?

Just in case if you want to see the comments:http://www.arrowlife.com/

The only resource I have with me is url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works: http://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arrowlife.com%2F%3Fsection%3DDestined-for-stardom

(Make sure you have the "http://" (encoded) in front of the url)

Comment: it does give me the result for destined for stardom..but not for others and how do i get all the entries..currently i am getting only one entry..example

http://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arrowlife.com%3Fsection%3DFashionably-Corporate

Comment: http://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arrowlife.com%2F%3Fsection%3DThe-Improviser also works (you were using an invalid URL with "section=section="), and I only see 1 comment there too (on arrowlife as well as in the facebook response). The Fashionably-Corporate one I'm not sure about yet...

Comment: should i get these using object-id or should i use this approach..?

Comment: using the url of the page is perfectly valid, as that is the id. See here http://graph.facebook.com/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arrowlife.com%2F%3Fsection%3DThe-Improviser . Facebook tells you this page's id is its url, and that it has one comment.  See this: http://graph.facebook.com/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arrowlife.com%2F%3Fsection%3DFashionably-Corporate . The id is the url, and you can see that there are no comments.

Comment: the thing is even when the no of comments increses on the page..they arent reflecting when i use your approach...
http://www.arrowlife.com/

Comment: thanks..it worked..i don know for some reason it is not showing comments from my own personal account..