# API For facebook comments plugin?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

Is there an API using which I can access facebook comment plugin comments?

At the moment, I retrieve the facebook internal id, by making this call to facebook API:

```
curl -i -X GET
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/http://somepage.com/foo-bar1?access_token=someaccesstoken"
```

I get back the following reponse:

```
{
  "og_object": {
    "id": "747775981962751",
    "description": "Some description.",
    "title": "Some title",
    "type": "website",
    "updated_time": "2017-01-22T16:52:05+0000"
  },
  "share": {
    "comment_count": 7,
    "share_count": 0
  },
  "id": "http://somepage.com/foo-bar1"
}
```

So the object ID for this url is: 747775981962751.

I query that, to get this response:

`{
  "created_time": "2014-10-12T11:40:34+0000",
  "title": "Some title",
  "type": "website",
  "id": "747775981962751"
}`

So according to the facebook docs, i should be able to access objects comments using this: `{object_id}/comments`,

But after sending the following query:

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/747775981962751/comments?access_token=someaccesstoken"
```

I get the following response:

`{
  "data": [
  ]
}`

So what's the deal? Is it possible for me to access website comments that were left via the facebook comments plug-in programatically?

I have full access to website's in question facebook admin panel, if that is any help?

Comment: Does the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19806802/1072229) work?

Comment: I get error:       "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.". I will try properly with access token and everything, when I get to my work computer. Thanks, I hope it will work!