# how to get facebook shares, comments, like count for youtube videos?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, youtube

I know how to query the social engagement counts for a regular website. It can be pretty easily achieved with the facebook graph explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) or throug api's. As path I supply the url of an object, e.g. an website e.g. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.manuelfink.de&version=v2.0

However if I try the same for a youtube movie https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DBpxVIwCbBK0&version=v2.0 it allways returns me the shared count of https://www.youtube.com/watch.

**Is it possible to get the facebook shared/likes count for an youtube movie?**

Thx, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

For share and like count, I think you can find an answer in the following questions on SO:
[Get top videos on facebook/twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182207/get-top-videos-on-facebook-twitter/24182531#24182531), which is based on
[How do you get the total likes for a URL (Likes and Shares)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746887/how-do-you-get-the-total-likes-for-a-url-likes-and-shares), and
[How to get share counts using graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270/how-to-get-share-counts-using-graph-api). Remember that a Youtube video has more than a possible url, so you may have to make several queries with different urls for the same video. I am not sure you can get the comments, but you can try with [how can I get all comments from a url in facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487831/how-can-i-get-all-comments-from-a-url-in-facebook)